# local variable 'n' referenced before assignment. Closures

Tags: python, closures

```
def fibonacci_closure(n):
    def fibonaci(): 
         if n == 0: """in this line error occured idk why because in watches i see n=4""" 
            return 0 
         elif n == 1 or n == 2:
            return 1 
         else:
            i = 1 
            j = 1 
            tmp = 1 
            while n != 2: 
                n -=1
                tmp = i 
                i = j + i 
                j = tmp 
            return i 
    return fibonaci

a = fibonacci_closure(4)

a()
```

**Task:**
Return a closure that will generate elements of the Fibonacci sequence when called repeatedly.
    Example:

```
    g = fibonacci_closure()
    g() # 1
    g() # 1
    g() # 2
    g() # 3
```

**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment**

Comment: The example does not have an argument `n`.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but idk how set fibonaci without some variable.

Comment: fix your indentation. why calculate the numbers from scratch each call to `g()`? Printing the numbers is not very usable, `return` the values and let the caller decide what he wants with the number

Comment: That was for testing if is result right. In final version will be return.

Comment: You need to specify `nonlocal n` at the beginning of the definition of `fibonaci`

Comment: Heike thx i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fibonacci numbers are a typical example for generators. It's only irritating why the function should return a function instead of a generator.

```
def fibonacci_closure():
    def fibonacci():
        i = j = 1
        while True:
            yield i
            i, j = j, i + j
    return fibonacci().__next__
```

Answer (score -1):

The task you are trying to accomplish could be done by creating a class. (Or you could look into creating a 'generator' object, which is its own separate thing.)

What you need in order to preserve the value of n from one call to the next is some sort of global variable. Global variables in Python are possible, but are bad practice. The same thing can be accomplished from within a class where n is stored and encapsulated within that class.

Have a look at the changes I made and see if the function now works as you intended. Cheers!

```
class fibonacci_closure():
    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0

    def fibonaci(self): 
        if self.n == 0:
            self.n+=1
            print(0) 
        elif self.n == 1 or self.n == 2:
            self.n+=1
            print(1) 
        else:
            i = 1 
            j = 1 
            tmp = 1
            hold = self.n 
            while hold != 2: 
                hold -=1
                tmp = i 
                i = j + i 
                j = tmp
            self.n+=1
            print(i)
```

Comment: Apologies for my first attempt. I failed to note the desired functionality of the program and took my answer down the wrong path. Hopefully, this version will hit closer to the mark.

Comment: To use this class, call: g = fibonacci_closure(), then call g.fibonaci() for each new value desired. This should function in the way you intended.

Comment: Why is it a class?

Comment: A class is used because we want hold on to values between calls to methods of the class. If we used a function, any variables used within the function are discarded once the function ends and those variables go out of scope. The variables within the class are persistent. Once assigned using g = fibonacci_closure(), the value assigned to class variable self.n are held on to until you call del g, or until the program ends. It's a way of having a global-like variable without engaging in the bad practice of using global variables. It's all about encapsulation.

Comment: More precisely, values stored within the class (here, using self.n) are held on to between method calls. All of the other variables used within the class are temporary because we did not stored them with the 'self.' prefix. They are lost once they go out of scope. Notice the __init__(self): method. This is a special method which is automatically called whenever you assign that class to a variable, as we did with 'g=fibonacci_closure()'. It is the perfect place to do any set-up work that the class needs to function. In this case, we declared and initiated self.n

Comment: This seems a rather complicated approach. Why not just store the n-th and (n+1)-th Fibonacci number as instance variables (`self.fib0` and `self.fib1`, say). Then in `fibonacci` you can simply update them using `self.fib0, self.fib1 = self.fib1, self.fib0 + self.fib1` and return `self.fib0`.

Comment: You could do that, and it would be much better code. But optimizing code is secondary to code that works and that you understand; especially when you are starting out, as I suspect this user is doing. This is why I tried to preserve as much of the user's original code as possible. My philosophy is that modern computers are fast and rich in resources; so if your code is clunky and inefficient, so what?! Computers are great at brute work, let them work. Why tie yourself into knots worrying that your code isn't OP. Enjoyment trumps OP. (Especially for the hobbiest.) Code now, refactor later.